# RhinoMocks - Stub a Method That Returns a Parameter

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks, stubbing

I am using RhinoMocks, I need to stub a method, and always have it return the third parameter, regardless of what is passed in:

```
_service.Stub(x => x.Method(parm1, parm2, parm3)).Return(parm3);
```

Obviously, it ain't that easy.  I don't always know what the parms are going to be, but I know I always want to return the 3rd one.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible. Could you post the method you are trying to test?

Comment: The method returns a call to another method from a static class.  Basically the call looks in the database to see if the first parameter is present, if it isn't, it returns the third parameter.

Comment: This is a piece of cake with Moq

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can provide an implementation for a method with the [Do() handler](http://www.ayende.com/Wiki/%28S%28crztahqxh521q1455e1gbc2y%29%29/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino+Mocks+The+Do%28%29+Handler&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1):

```
Func<TypeX,TypeY,TypeZ,TypeZ> returnThird = (x,y,z) => z;
mock.Expect(x => x.Method(null, null, null)).IgnoreArguments().Do(returnThird);
```

Note that `TypeZ` appears twice because it is both an input argument type and the return type.

Comment: This is using `.Expect()` instead of `.Stub()` as in the question.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
        _service
            .Stub(x => x.Method(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, ... ))
            .Return(null) // ... or default(T): will be ignored but RhinoMock requires it
            .WhenCalled(x =>
            {
                // This will be used as the return value
                x.ReturnValue = (string) x.Arguments[0];
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the expect method with a callback to return the value that you are after. The following will return null.

```
_service.Expect(o => o.Method(null, null, null))
        .Callback((object parm1, object parm2, object parm3) => { return parm3; });
```

I am not sure if you can use Callback on Stub.

Comment: I tried this, but the Callback delegate expects me to return a bool and not an object. How can I return object based on argment. This is in essence what I want to do: `_mockFactory.Stub(_ => _.Create(null, null, null)).IgnoreArguments().Callback((object a1, object a2, object a3) => MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<MyObject>(a1, a2, a3));` but I get the error "Cannot convert type `MyObject` to `bool`". Any suggestions?